# Question wrongly flagged as spam/offensive

Tags: support

I set up a puzzle https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/49939 which was quickly removed as spam/offensive.

At first it looks bizarre,but it is a genuine puzzle with a solution.
It seems that other puzzlers haven't realized that it is in fact a legitimate puzzle and simply automatically flagged it as spam.

Now it has been removed(together with 100 reputation!).Is there any way to re-open it as being wrongly flagged-and is there any way to recover the reputation?

Comment: It may have been a legitimate puzzle, sure. But that's not a magical safeguard against the literal text of the puzzle coming across poorly.

Comment: Also, the 30 character minimum on questions is there for a reason. It's not just there to inconvenience you - if you're posting a puzzle with less than 30 characters, it is quite likely that we need more information.

Comment: But then it's not spam or offensive which it has been flagged as-it's just 'we don't understand this puzzle'...or 'what are you trying to do here'? A bewildering puzzle isn't an offensive one surely

Comment: What makes it potentially offensive isn't that it's bewildering. It's that it's asking what sounds like a sexually-loaded question about a fictional character who for much of her appearance in the fiction in question is a minor. (It would be kinda-creepy-sounding even without that last point, but that definitely makes it worse.)

Comment: Having said which, if indeed there is some (in retrospect) Obviously Right Answer to the question that was asked (so as to make the puzzle a legitimate one despite its creepiness) then I'm kinda intrigued as to what it is, simply because on the face of it that seems so unlikely. On the other hand, precisely because it seems so unlikely I can't help suspecting that there really isn't, and that at best there's some kind of pun-based joke answer or something like that...

Answer (score 1):

The puzzle wasn't flagged as "not a legitimate puzzle" - it was flagged because the text of the puzzle was asking a creepy question. Flaggers don't need to know the answer to the question - or even identify it as a puzzle at all - in order to make that judgment call.

It may have been a legitimate puzzle, and I don't think that possibility was ignored. I was one of those flaggers, and I considered that, too. But being a real puzzle isn't a safeguard against the content of a question being off-putting and, well, frankly kind of inappropriate to post here.

Answer (score 0):

Well for those who wanted to know the answer even though the puzzle is deleted:

> The title is 'Beware the Bat Bogey' ... which is a HEX (which Miss Weasley is particularly skilled at, which is why she was chosen), so it's something to do with hexadecimal.
>  If you read literally, the size of **Ginevra Weasley's bra** in number of letters is 783.If you convert that to hexadecimal, you get your answer — 30f.

Comment: There's nothing indicating that you need to take the lengths of the words *separately* rather than as a string or the length of the ASCII representation (aka number of bits). Even if this puzzle *weren't* asking a very creepy question, it'd be downvoted horribly because it's an exercise in mind-reading.